# Building political compass in ggplot, how can I make this code more concise?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

So I successfully made a political compass in R with data from my friends which looks like this:

```
Name    Economic    Social  House   Gender
Jimmy   -3.75        -2.46  B St    Male
Beth    -4.75        -7.38  A St    Female
```

The code works fine, but I feel like I wrote too much code to get what I wanted, how can I reduce the amount of code written to get the same result.

Also, it would be nice to have the `geom_hline/geom_vline` to stop where the squares stop, any Ideas on how to do this??

Code:

```
df <- data.frame(
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                  Name = c("Jimmy", "Beth"),
              Economic = c(-0.04, -4.75),
                Social = c(-2.46, -7.38),
                 House = c("B St", "A St"),
                Gender = c("Male", "Female"))

ggplot(df,aes(Economic,Social, color = House))+
  xlim(-10,10)+
  ylim(-10,10)+
  annotate("rect", xmin = 0, xmax = 10, ymin = 0, ymax = 10, fill= "deepskyblue3")  + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = -10, xmax = 0, ymin = -10, ymax = 0 , fill= "palegreen1") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = 0, xmax = 10, ymin = -10, ymax = 0, fill= "plum3") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = -10, xmax = 0, ymin = 0, ymax = 10, fill= "indianred1") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0) +
  geom_point(size = 4)+
  ggtitle("The Gang gets Political")+
  theme_minimal()+
  geom_text(aes(label=Name),hjust=0, vjust=0, size =4, color = "black")+ 
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+
  geom_text(
    label="Authoritarian", 
    x=0,
    y=10.5,
    color = "azure4"
  )+
  geom_text(
    label="Libertatian", 
    x=0,
    y=-10.5,
    color = "azure4"
  )+
  geom_text(
    label="Left", 
    x=-10.5,
    y=0,
    color = "azure4"
  )+
  geom_text(
    label="Right", 
    x=10.5,
    y=0,
    color = "azure4"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do that will streamline the plotting
a) Use colour for the annotate elements to add a black border which removes the need for the vline and hlines
b) Use the theme_void to avoid needing to supress so many theme elements from theme_minimal
c) Use a second data set which has the political orientation labels and desired positions so that they can be created using a single geom_text geom

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Name = c("Jimmy", "Beth"),
          Economic = c(-0.04, -4.75),
            Social = c(-2.46, -7.38),
             House = c("B St", "A St"),
            Gender = c("Male", "Female")
)

labels <- data.frame(label = c("Authoritarian","Libertarian","Left","Right"),
                 x = c(0, 0, -10.5, 10.5),
                 y = c(10.5, -10.5, 0, 0)
          )

ggplot(df,aes(Economic,Social, color = House))+
  annotate("rect", xmin = 0, xmax = 10, ymin = 0, ymax = 10, fill= "deepskyblue3", color = "black")  + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = -10, xmax = 0, ymin = -10, ymax = 0, fill= "palegreen1", color = "black") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = 0, xmax = 10, ymin = -10, ymax = 0, fill= "plum3", color = "black") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = -10, xmax = 0, ymin = 0, ymax = 10, fill= "indianred1", color = "black") + 
  geom_point(size = 4)+
  ggtitle("The Gang gets Political")+
  theme_void()+
  geom_text(aes(label=Name),hjust=0, vjust=0, size = 4, color = "black") + 
  geom_text(data = labels, color = "azure4", aes(x, y, label = label))
```

[image: Image of the graph generated by the above code]